# compare contents of two directories on remote server using unix

Tags: unix, diff, ksh, rsync, vimdiff

I am new to unix and need some help here.
I have two directories present on two different server. both the directories contains the same files. Now i want to check if all files are in sync in both the directories. If files are not in sync then i want to display only name of those files.
I am able to do it when directories are on same server. not able to figure out how to do this when directories are present on two different servers.

```
eg:
server1 /abc/home/sample1/
server2 /abc/home/sample2/
```

here i want only files name to display when it not in sync.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mount the two servers on a common system and *compare the way you do as usual*.

Comment: can't we achieve this using diff, rsync or vimdiff

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use rsync with the `-n` flag to find out if the files are in sync, without actually doing a sync.

For example, from **server1**:

```
rsync -n -avrc /abc/home/sample1/* server2:/abc/home/sample2/
```

This will print the names of all files (recursive, with the `-r` flag) that differ between `server1:/abc/home/sample1/` and `server2:/abc/home/sample2/`

> `rsync` used parameters explanation
>
> `-n, --dry-run` - perform a trial run with no changes made
>
> `-a, --archive` - archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
>
> `-v, --verbose` - increase verbosity
>
> `-r, --recursive` - recurse into directories
>
> `-c, --checksum` - **skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size**

Comment: Great answer.  The `-c` here is super important, as it compares by checksum specifically. I was getting false positives without it. `-a` implies `-r` (unless you are using `--files-from`)

Comment: Just to sum it up. You want `rsync -avcn folder1/ folder2/`.

Comment: The backslash at the end of the folder name is really important. Missing the backslash will cause rsync print names of all files.

Comment: I had to look this up, but it's useful to note that `-n` is just a shorthand for `--dry-run`

Comment: A summary of the rsync flags used:

`-n` Dry run (do not actually transfer any files, super important)
- `-a` Archive mode (preserve symlinks, permissions, timestamps...)
- `-v` Verbose output
- `-r` Recursive
- `-c` Compare using checksum instead of timestamp+filesize. This is important to avoid false positives as the two locations might not have matching timestamps.

Comment: Can we match file names on pattern and compare results with rsync? Like, ./dir1 "compare these files with pattern" remote:/path/dir2 "pattern"

Comment: @kielni adding on to this, if you are looking to get only the file names to use in some other part of your script, what you can do is drop the `-v` verbose option and add on `--out-format=%n`.  When used together with command substitution, you would get the file names as a single string delimited by whitespace

Answer (score 10):

On server1:

```
cd /abc/home/sample1/ && diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines <(find . -type f|xargs stat --printf "%s\t%n\n"|sort -n) <(ssh server2 "cd /abc/home/sample2/ && find . -type f|xargs stat --printf \"%s\t%n\n\"|sort -n")
```

This is pretty fast but probably not as accurate as rsync since it uses file size instead of hash of content.  Also, the rsync from kielni's answer will not show anything if server2 has more files then server1.  Instead try this:

```
rsync -n -avr --size-only --delete /abc/home/sample1/ server2:/abc/home/sample2/
```

Comment: Your rsync command should be the accepted answer as it is the only one that works.

Comment: --delete is needed to show if a file exists on server 2 but not server 1, the accepted answer does not show that

Answer (score 1):

I always use `rsync -avcn` for such tasks - I am a CLI fan. The idea is to do a "dry run" (`-n`), which shows what would have been done without actually copying any files or making any changes. Using the `-c` switch is really important as it uses the checksum rather than the modification date or file size to determine if the files are different. `-a` makes sure that the comparison is more thorough and it forces the program to dive into the subdirectories. Finally, `-v` increases the level of verbosity, which is useful in case different files are found.

So a possible solution goes something like this:

```
rsync -avcn source_dir/ dest_dir/
```

and `rsync` will print the names of the files that are different between the two directories. Note the trailing slashes - they are essential.

**However:**

1. if there are many different files, the list soon fills up the terminal screen and becomes hard to read. In this case it is better to redirect the output to a file: `rsync -avcn source_dir/ dest_dir/ > diffs.txt`
2. this might sound silly but remember to escape the spaces if the source or destination directory has them. Alternatively, you can enclose them in quotation marks. `rsync -avcn /src/My Dir/ dest/My dir/` is not what you want; rather, you should use `rsync -avcn /src/My\ Dir/ dest/My\ Dir/` or perhaps `rsync -avcn /src/"My Dir"/ dest/"My Dir"/`. This point is especially valid when dealing with Windows mounts.

Answer (score -1):

In scenario of no connectivity between two servers, use "tree" command to get directory structure in files and then diff two files.