# shell script to compare same directories in different host

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have to sync a directory containing list of files with different content in two host.

Suppose there are two host - ap1.123.1.2 and ap2.123.2.2 and both contain director /opt/abc and /opt/abc.While both contain N number of files.

something like below
On host - ap1.123.1.2

```
ls -l /opt/abc 
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
e.txt
```

and on host - ap2.123.2.2

```
ls -l /opt/abc
a.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

Now I have to create a script to make sure both folders are in sync
something like below
.
In host - ap1 and ap2, both should contain same number of files in their respective directory.

```
ls -l /opt/abc

a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare contents of two directories on remote server using unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396718/compare-contents-of-two-directories-on-remote-server-using-unix)

Comment: what do you want to happen if the a.txt  on ap1 has different content/timestamp from a.txt on ap2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rsync to do the comparison.

[This Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57305/rsync-compare-directories) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396718/compare-contents-of-two-directories-on-remote-server-using-unix) might be what you're looking for.

From the second link:

> `rsync -n -avrc /abc/home/sample1/* server2:/abc/home/sample2/`

Comment: shouldn't need to use delete for this case, just -u in both directions

Comment: but this is in same host, while I  have two different host. Where i have to ssh to first host get the list , scp to another host and then ssh to another host . get list and compare and then find unique elements. Then scp missing files from one host to another and vice versa.