# Redactor/HTMLPurifier won't allow entry update CraftCMS

Tags: htmlpurifier, redactor, craftcms

I'm fairly new to all this.... can you guys help me work out what is wrong here?

Most of my site is fine. When I try to edit a Redactor Field however, I get the error

`Class 'HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_HTML_ContentEditable' not found`

If I press "Save" it just gives me a craft styled INTERNAL SERVER ERROR page

Stack Trace from craft's web.log file... This happens when trying to save an entry on my production server (DigitalOcean, RunCloud). Works fine on my development stack (Lando)

```
2022-10-11 16:51:02 [-][1][u3gqq1j4ho4jmi8dnbbdtm0e9u][error][Error] Error: Class 'HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_HTML_ContentEditable' not found in /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/AttrTypes.php:44
Stack trace:
#0 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLModuleManager.php(77): HTMLPurifier_AttrTypes->__construct()
#1 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLDefinition.php(187): HTMLPurifier_HTMLModuleManager->__construct()
#2 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/Config.php(630): HTMLPurifier_HTMLDefinition->__construct()
#3 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/Config.php(611): HTMLPurifier_Config->initDefinition()
#4 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/HtmlPurifier.php(51): HTMLPurifier_Config->getDefinition()
#5 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtmlPurifier.php(53): craft\helpers\HtmlPurifier::configure()
#6 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/html-field/src/HtmlField.php(193): yii\helpers\BaseHtmlPurifier::process()
#7 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/redactor/src/Field.php(506): craft\htmlfield\HtmlField->serializeValue()
#8 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Element.php(2150): craft\redactor\Field->serializeValue()
#9 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/InlineValidator.php(84): craft\base\Element->validateCustomFieldContentSize()
#10 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/Validator.php(261): yii\validators\InlineValidator->validateAttribute()
#11 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php(367): yii\validators\Validator->validateAttributes()
#12 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Elements.php(2562): yii\base\Model->validate()
#13 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Elements.php(785): craft\services\Elements->_saveElementInternal()
#14 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/EntriesController.php(407): craft\services\Elements->saveElement()
#15 [internal function]: craft\controllers\EntriesController->actionSaveEntry()
#16 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#17 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#18 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#19 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(293): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#20 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(602): craft\web\Application->runAction()
#21 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(272): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest()
#22 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
#23 /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#24 {main}
```

Also get this in the log sometimes?

`[12-Oct-2022 15:38:55 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'GuzzleHttp\ClientTrait' not found in /home/teraukura/webapps/Te_Raukura/Te-Raukura/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 17`

Comment: Naively, this looks like an inconsistent composer installation state, or issues with autoloading. That said, I assume you have `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` in your `index.php`, since you mentioned it works on your dev stack, so see if you can get a diff between the files available in the prod system and your dev setup?

Comment: Is there any easy way to check this? A comparison tool?

Comment: You could use an rsync dryrun if the prod server supports it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19410791/245790